# Remove elements with same date from JSONArray

Tags: java, arrays, json

So, I have to sort a JSONArray which contains JSONObject. 
 
The strucuture of the JSON is like the following:

```
[
  {
    "id": 582,
    "isTransaction": false,
    "toDate": "2015-08-26 16:12:00.0",
    "fromDate": "2015-08-24 15:11:00.0",
    "status": "REQUEST_ACCEPTED_BY_BOTH_SIDES"
  },
  {
    "id": 602,
    "isTransaction": false,
    "toDate": "2015-08-21 21:52:00.0",
    "fromDate": "2015-08-20 23:53:00.0",
    "status": "REQUEST_ACCEPTED_BY_BOTH_SIDES"
  }, {
    "carFk": 1,
    "endMileage": 1455,
    "ownerName": "Celien",
    "model": "335i",
    "status": "DRIVER_SET_ODOMETER",
    "ownerId": 1,
    "toDate": "2015-08-26 16:12:00.0",
    "startMileage": 455,
    "id": 421,
    "fromDate": "2015-08-24 15:11:00.0",
    "isTransaction": true,
    "brand": "Bmw",
    "driverName": "Damien",
    "exchange": false
  }
]
```

What I have to do is to delete all The JSONObjects which have the same *fromDate* field. If two object have this same field, then I would like to keep the one wich contains the field **isTransaction:true**

Here is the algortithm I wrote :

```
 private void addOnlyRequestOrTransactionIntoListView(JSONArray array) {
        JSONArray copyArray = array;
        JSONArray resultArray = new JSONArray();

        int i = 0, j = 0;
        try {
            while(i < array.length()){
                JSONObject temp = array.getJSONObject(i);
                j = 0;
                while(j < copyArray.length()){
                    if(temp.getString("fromDate").equals(array.getJSONObject(j).getString("fromDate")))
                        if(temp.getBoolean("isTransaction"))
                            resultArray.put(temp);                             
                    j++;
                }
                i++;
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

But it does not what I want to performed. 
 
Can you give me some clues?
Thanks!

Comment: Try out your algorithm with pencil and paper (playing computer) with a small example. You will soon recognize whats wrong.

Comment: I did it. I knwo that i will only add the JsonObject with the "isTransaction" set to true. How can avoid this behaviour?

Comment: @Mornor copyArray and array are both pointing to same place. Why have you used them as if they are two different arrays?

Comment: You should note that `JSONArray copyArray = array;` does not actually copy your array, it just passes the array reference to a new field which you call `copyArray`

Comment: @SureshS +1 for being faster

Comment: That doesn't matter though, since he only uses copyarray to get the length.

Comment: Yep, sorry that was an old version of the algorithm. I am updating my question.

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing every element with every element, including with itself. You should skip any case where `i == j`

So instead of:

```
if(temp.getString("fromDate").equals(array.getJSONObject(j).getString("fromDate")))
```

Use:

```
if(i != j && temp.getString("fromDate").equals(array.getJSONObject(j).getString("fromDate")))
```